# Finding Wallet Password Using Known Private Key

Tags: wallets, private-key

I have a bit of an odd question, I have two wallet files that I encrypted a few years ago, both of them have the same password, I have the private key for one of the wallet json files (MEW structure). I know it's unlikely, but is it possible for me to identify the password of the wallet using the private key when I have that alongside the wallet.json containing the ciphertext, salt and other relevant info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). The algorithm used by Ethereum keystore files (usually AES-128) is resistant to these kinds of attacks, and doing a known-plaintext attack would essentially be bruteforcing the password.

For reference:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58656/can-i-find-the-encryption-key-if-i-know-the-plain-text-and-the-encrypted-text-d
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks